Sharing PagingData between two recylerviews in Android
I've two recyclerview and need to share the same PagingDataFlow into both, so they can display the same data ( some horizontal scrolling issue, so some data will be on left some will be on the right)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val pagingDataFlow =
                viewModel.getBusinessvRecords(recordSearchRequest)

            try {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    pagingDataFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->

                        binding.recyclerViewLeft.post {
                            pagingAdapterLeft.submitData(lifecycle, pagingData)
                        }
                    }
                }

                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    pagingDataFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
                        binding.recyclerViewRight.post {
                            pagingAdapterRight.submitData(lifecycle, pagingData)
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.tag("Exception ").e("$e")
            }
        }


I'm getting crush, as
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{b2ae6b VFED..... ......I. 0,75-220,97 #7f0a0546 app:id/recyclerViewLeft}, adapter:androidx.recyclerview.widget.ConcatAdapter@8ab89d8, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@efb0dc8, context:dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper@ca861d7
Is there a solution to my problem that doesn't crush for Android 29+ versions?

what is the difference between both adapters? where does concatadapter come into play? also lifecyclescope.launch is not a correct way to feed view layer in a fragment

@Pawel lifecycleScope.launch is the correct way to collect data from view model, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement-viewmodel. The problem is submitting data changes while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling. kelalaka Can you add submitData() function to your question? I guess you are using notifyDataSetChanged(). Use AsyncListDiffer instead.

@KaungKhantKyaw there is nothing special about my submitData(), it is from PagingDataAdapter.kt. Before Sharing, only one gets the data, after sharing, it crushes.

@Pawel not so much, the first ( or a few) data will be displayed with the left recyclerview, and the rest will be displayed with the right one, so on horizontal scroll, the left will stay where it is.

@KaungKhantKyaw actually in fragment anything that touches views should be setup onviewcreated and running on viewlifecycleowner.lifecycleScope.

@Pawel the adapters are set in onviewcreated and the adapters are working if I try to send the data to any of them. The problem started when I tried to feed the same paging data to them. lifecycleScope is already used before and later.
